# Android: call a separate class to return value

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to store the value of the GPS coordinates that are in one class to another. Basically I have a button and currently I used an intent to change layout that displays the coordinates. I want to store the coords on the button click but I'm not sure whether you should use an intent, a run() , or anything.

The code I want to pull from is this:

```
public class gps extends Activity implements LocationListener {
//
// body
//

    private void printLocation(Location location) {
        output2.append("Lat:"+location.getLatitude()+"\nLong: "+location.getLongitude());
        latitude = Math.round(location.getLatitude());
        longitude = Math.round(location.getLongitude());

         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Lat: " + latitude + "| Long: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }
```

where the values are store in "latitude" and "longitude"

I use this to change between screens:

```
Button gpsbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gps); //temp use of gps button
gpsbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent gpsIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), gps.class);
        startActivityForResult(gpsIntent, 0);

    }


    });
```

All I want is to store a numeric value.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass those values from one activity to another (you didn't specify exactly what you wanted to do with latitude and longitude) you'd add them as extras in the Intent you use either to call startActivityForResult() (if starting a new activity) or setResult() (if returning to a previous activity).

Comment: I use this for to change screens currently:
Intent gpsIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), gps.class);
 startActivityForResult(gpsIntent, 0);

Comment: So you want this gps class to return those two values to the activity that calls gps?  

Pack the values into an intent at the end of the above code, either directly using setExtra() or using a Bundle object.

`code`Test